# Handling JSON data in R

Tags: r

So I have nested JSON data as shown below,

```
{
  "School_Days" :[
      {
          "ts" : 1234,
          "val": "ABC"
      },

     {
          "ts" : 0987,
          "val": "EFG"
     }
                 ]

}
```

So when I create a data frame it creates a dataframe but it has `4 columns` and `1 row` instead of `2 columns` and `2 rows`

below is my code for parsing the Json data,

```
sc_data <- content(school_json,"parsed", "application/json","Accept: 
application/json")

sc_df <- data.frame(sc_data, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

`Current Dataframe`

```
 School_Days.ts       School_Days.Val     School_Days.ts1   School_Days.val1
   123                     ABC               0987              EFG
```

`Expected DataFrame`

```
 School_Days.ts       School_Days.Val
   123                     ABC         
   0987                    EFG
```

NOTE: I am currently fetching JSON data from and REST API `GET` call and store it in `school_json`

Also, `typeof(school_json)` results as `List` which is of the following format,

```
$School_Days
$School_Days[[1]]
$School_Days[[1]]$ts
[1] 1234

$School_Days[[1]]$Val
[1] "ABC"

$School_Days[[2]]
$School_Days[[2]]$ts
[1] 0987

$School_Days[[2]]$Val
[1] "EFG"
```

Comment: have you tried `jsonlite` and `fromJSON`

Comment: have you tried `jsonlite` and `fromJSON`

Comment: @Chris, Thanks from Responding, `"application/json"` in the `Content` function use functionalities of `fromJSON`. well `?content()` shows that

Comment: `content` is not a base function, please include library calls to your post

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper, Oh I believe it is wrong. `content` is a based function. Well I didn't use library to call that function

Comment: It's not, most likely it's from `httr`, what appears at the bottom when you type `content`? inside `<environment: namespace:******>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here I found the solution to my question,

I did the following changes to my `content()` function,

```
sc_data <- content(school_json,"text", "application/json")
sc_df <- fromJSON(sc_data, flatten = TRUE)
sc_df <- data.frame(sc_df,stringAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Instead of retrieving as `"parsed"` I retrieved it as `"text"` which gave me `JSON` data in the form of `String`.